# VSCode doesnt style the content inside of Template Strings

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, graphql

I just realize that there are two situations (as far as I know) that my **VSCode** doesn't **"style"** the content inside of my **template strings**.
One is when I am writing **CSS** on a javascript file and the other is when I am trying to get data from **GraphQL.**
I will explain!

Following is my code and then the result:

```js
 const SyleHero = styled.header`
  min-height: 60vh;
  background: url("./images/defaultBcg.jpeg") center/cover no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;
```

I can see the text inside of the backticks in green like this:

[image]

But the result I would like to have is this following one:

[image]

My code works fine the way it is but I believe would be much more handy if I could see my code like in the image above.

Does anyone know how can I have the same result?

Thank you all!

Comment: I have [Babel Javascript extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel) installed, but I'm not sure if it's still needed today.

Comment: How is vscode supposed to know what the content of the string (not the template/dynamic part) actually is? In the end it's just a string with the option of adding/"executing" code in it.

Comment: Thank you Emile! I just installed the Babel and know I can see it "styled" haha!

Answer (score 1):

install "vscode-styled-components" from extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to install a extention in vs code to highlight the css syntax.
Extention name is 'vscode-styled-components'.
Once installed refresh your vs code and it will work.